react-native-background-actions ( service stopped Android 14 )
React Community...
This is my first question here
I am using "react-native-background-actions" library to run task in background even if user kill the app.
But i am facing issue that after some hours the background service is killed. But in android 14 the service is killed after some minutes and app stop responding.
Give me a solution to use the infinite background service.
Developer.android.com ( android 14 behaviour changes )
I see on google policy I see this on official updates of android 14 
I try to run the infinite service in the background but the service stops after some hours and in Android 14 app stops responding .

In androidmenifest.xml :
Add service in application tag
if already exist foregroundServiceType should be dataSync
android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
<service android:name="com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask" android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"/>

and make sure in node_modules react-native-background-actions folder RNBackgroundActionsTask.java file
final PendingIntent contentIntent;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_ALLOW_UNSAFE_IMPLICIT_INTENT);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        } else {
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }

is there
